# Assign the result of stored procedure into a variable using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, variables, stored-procedures

I'm new to Entity Framework ORM while using DataSet ORM I can simply assign a stored procedure result to a variable like

```
 MyDataSetTblAdapter MyData = new MyDataSetTblAdapter();
 string Result = Mydata.MyStoredProcedure().ToString();
```

And it works fine .. but in Entity Framework I'm trying the same

```
OnlineDvdShopDbEntities dbContext = new OnlineDvdShopDBEntities();
String Result = DbContext.SpAddGetUsername().ToString();
```

Remember my stored procedure is returning a single value

Comment: Which method are you using? Code first, model first, or database first?

Comment: Database first 
i generated the model using Database entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.

```
    // Initialize dependency to data entities
    private Entities _dataContext;
    public ClassName()
    {
        _dataContext = new Entities();
    }

    public IQueryable<EntityName> MethodName(string filter)
    {
        // Initialize 
        var records = _dataContext.Entity

                 // Constrain your results
                 .Where(
                         x => filter == null
                         || x.Property1.Contains(filter)
                       );
        return records;
    }
```

If you are only expecting a single value then you might use

```
var records = _dataContext.Entity.FirstrDefault();
```

FirstOrDefault() basically returns the first element of the sequence that would match your criteria. You could also use SingleOrDefault(), given then need for only one result.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @ShaikhNomanNasir Awesome. If you are satisfied, please mark it as the answer. You can find more on Entity Framework (database first) at https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Comment: My Reputation is not enough to mark an answer or vote it up .. Sorry

Comment: No worries. I updated my answer a little to explain the usages of FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault(). These will help when using linq to entities. ToString() will only convert the entity it's self into a string literal. You could also go as far as using `.DefaultIfEmpty(YourCustomDefault)` if you need a default value other than null for empty results.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() worked for me.. and i never knew their usages before.. :) 
Thanks again (Y)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The op asked how to get the result of a stored procedure. This answer shows how to get the result of querying an entity.